# Difference between using JAVA_HOME=... and export JAVA_HOME=$(...)

Tags: bash, macos

Up until now I've been setting environmental variables using something like:

`JAVA_HOME=...`

From this https://xenovation.com/blog/development/java/how-to-set-java-home, I can set it using:

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

Could someone explain:

1. Why `echo $JAVA_HOME` shows `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home`
2. I understand that `export JAVA_HOME=...` sets an environment variable. What does adding `$(...)` do?
3. Would `export JAVA_HOME=(/usr/libexec/java_home)` be the same thing as export `JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home`?

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- `/usr/libexec/java_home` is an executable that can give you proper value for JAVA_HOME, it also can be used by arguments. for example `/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.7*'` will give you sutiable value for `JAVA_HOME` in order to use Java 7. `$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` will give you path to `JAVA_HOME` which in your case will be `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home`.

2- `$(...)` is for command substitution. for example:

```
a=$(echo foo) # results a="foo"
```

3- they're not the same in concept! `export JAVA_HOME=(/usr/libexec/java_home)` will assign an array to `JAVA_HOME` but `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home` ill assign an string path to it. if you `echo $JAVA_HOME` it will show the first element of array which in your case because you have only one element, it will result into the same thing. It means `export JAVA_HOME=(/usr/libexec/java_home)` and `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home` will be the same.

NOTE: `/usr/libexec/java_home` is only a binary file which points to real `JAVA_HOME`. you must execute it with `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` to get true result!